# Magento Exclude Product view

Tags: magento-1.9

How to display exclude images on magento product view page.
I'm using magento 1.9

Comment: Instead of showing excluded images, why not to changes the status exclude to not-exclude  ?

Comment: or you want all images whether its exclude ot include  to display on product view page?? right ?

Comment: Hi want to display particular product exclude images on separate div

Comment: check the answer

Comment: it will show the both enable and disable images of image gallery,

Answer (score 0):

To get all images of product including exclude images in magento , you can look at the Mage_Catalog_Model_Product, override this core file on local.

```
public function getMediaGalleryImages()
{
if(!$this->hasData('media_gallery_images') && is_array($this->getMediaGallery('images'))) {
$images = new Varien_Data_Collection();
foreach ($this->getMediaGallery('images') as $image) {
if ($image['disabled']) {
continue;
}
$image['url'] = $this->getMediaConfig()->getMediaUrl($image['file']);
$image['id'] = isset($image['value_id']) ? $image['value_id'] : null;
$image['path'] = $this->getMediaConfig()->getMediaPath($image['file']);
$images->addItem(new Varien_Object($image));
}
$this->setData('media_gallery_images', $images);
}

return $this->getData('media_gallery_images');
```

Magento media attribute a have field name disabled or exclude which tell which image are in excluded list check:

```
foreach (Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getId())->getMediaGalleryImages() as $_image){
                if( $_image->getExclude()==1){
                $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'thumbnail', $_image->getFile())->resize(301);
                }
            }
```

Comment: Thanks But i need only separate view for excluded product

Comment: can I get the  collection of every excluded images of that product ? from that you can show what you want

Comment: yes but i need to view every product excluded images on that particular product view page. I need to display like this https://global.rakuten.com/en/store/koreda/item/ts0040103908_15839/

Comment: updated the answer

Comment: But it will fetch all excluded product form the db. i need based on product id

Comment: $prod = 4542;
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($prod);

foreach ($product->getMediaGallery('images') as $img) {
    if ($img['disabled'] == 1) {
        var_dump($img['label']);
    }


}

Comment: edited answer..

Comment: <?php
    $_product = $this->getProduct();
    $_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output');
?>
<?php 
   $prod = "2153";
   $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($prod);
 foreach ($product->getMediaGallery('images') as $img) 
 { 
 if ($img['disabled'] == 1) {
  //var_dump($img['label']);
  ?>
  <img class="gallery-image visible" src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($this->getProduct(), 'thumbnail', $img->getFile())->resize(730,468); ?>"/>
         <?php
  } 
 }
?>

Comment: i'm using above code on view page but it;s not working

Comment: i have updated the answer, use that one

Comment: foreach (Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getId())->getMediaGalleryImages() as $_image){
                if( $_image->getExclude()==1){
                $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'thumbnail', $_image->getFile())->resize(301);
                }
            }

Comment: <?php
    $_product = $this->getProduct();
    //$_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output');
 
?>
<?php 
   //$prod = "2153";
  // $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($prod);
   
   
   
   foreach (Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getId())->getMediaGalleryImages() as $_image){ 
   if( $_image->getExclude()==1){ 
   echo "working";
   ?>
    <img class="gallery-image visible" src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'thumbnail', $_image->getFile())->resize(301); ?>"/>
   <?php
   
   }
 else{  echo "false"; }} 
?>

Comment: I used above but it didn't display and it goes to false even i have added exclude image using backend